# Query execution errors after upgrading spring boot 3.2.0 to 3.2.1

Tags: java, spring, hql

i have a Java Spring application with lots of queries, which so far have worked until spring boot **3.2.0**.

Recently, after simply changing to spring boot **3.2.1**, I started getting this kind of error:

```
org.hibernate.query.sqm.produce.function.FunctionArgumentException: Function argument [org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.expression.SqmLiteralNull@5bd97ebe] of type [org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.expression.NullSqmExpressible@3f8a721f] at specified position [2] in call arguments was not typed as an allowable function return type
```

My pom dependencies look like this:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc11</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

My queries, with some code i cant disclose removed, but still giving errors, has simple conditions:

```
    
    @Query("select org  "
         + "  from Organization         org     "
         + " where 1 = 1 "
         + "   and ( "
         + "         coalesce(:#{#request.name},null) is null "
         + "         or "
         + "         trim(:#{#request.name}) = '' "
         + "         or "
         + "         lower(org.name) like lower(trim(:#{#request.name}))"
         + "       ) "
    )
    Page<Organization> getPageByCriteria(@Param("request") GetOrganizationsRequestDto request, Pageable pageable);
```

I am connecting to **oracle database version 11g**

Does anyone have this kind of problem or similar and can help me with it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a minimum reproducable code?

Comment: Can be reproduced with the elements give above. The pom dependencies, a oracle 11g database, a single table "Organization" with a column "name" (string) and a repository with the above query. Then it simply needs to be called. I believe the problem might be related to some oracle limitation for most recent versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coalesce expected non-null parameters, so you should remove `null` parameter.

Transform from your original method, it should be same with this:

```
select org from Organization org
where 1 = 1
and (:#{#request.name} is null
   or trim(:#{#request.name}) = ''
   or lower(org.name) like lower(trim(:#{#request.name}))
)
```

Comment: Even doing that it gives the same error :(

Comment: @user1508072 find all your coalesce with null parameter and update it. I have reproduced it & solve by update the query.

Comment: that indeed solved it! Thanks. Now i have another error

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: JDBC exception executing SQL ... ORA-00933 - command not properly ended

I will open another question for it.