# Query execution errors after upgrading spring boot 3.2.0 to 3.2.1 - ORA-00933 - command not properly ended

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, hql

I have a Java Spring application with lots of queries, which so far have worked until spring boot **3.2.0**.

Recently, after simply changing to spring boot **3.2.1**, I started getting this kind of error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: JDBC exception executing 
SQL [select 
        o1_0.org_id,
        o1_0.name 
     from organizations o1_0 
     where (
            ? is null or 
            trim(BOTH from ?)='' or 
            lower(o1_0.name) like lower(trim(BOTH from ?))
     ) 
     offset ? rows 
     fetch first ? rows only] 
[ORA-00933: comando SQL command not properly ended]
```

My pom dependencies look like this:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc11</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

My queries, with some code i cant disclose removed, but still giving errors, has simple conditions:

```
    
    @Query("select org  "
         + "  from Organization         org     "
         + " where 1 = 1 "
         + "   and ( "
         + "         :#{#request.name} is null "
         + "         or "
         + "         trim(:#{#request.name}) = '' "
         + "         or "
         + "         lower(org.name) like lower(trim(:#{#request.name}))"
         + "       ) "
    )
    Page<Organization> getPageByCriteria(@Param("request") GetOrganizationsRequestDto request, Pageable pageable);
```

I am connecting to **oracle database version 11g**

Does anyone have this kind of problem or similar and can help me with it? I suspect it is related to ojdbc not having had an update since the last spring boot version.

Thanks

**Edit**: added the pure SQL query performed on the database, according to error log

Comment: add a full stack trace, please. It would be useful to set loggin level to DEBUG:
`logging.level.org.hibernate.sql=DEBUG` in the application.properties

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77809749 but cannot be closed because of bounty.

Comment: It is not duplicate. The error is different. the previous issue, once solved, led to this one. It is a step by step problem solving. I will put the log soon

Comment: @YuriyTsarkov i added the query performed on database, according to error log

Comment: That is dialect issue, offset rows fetch syntax was introduced in 12c, you are on 11g

Comment: Did you try to execute generated sql directly in the db?

Comment: @YuriyTsarkov yes, the problem is the "offset rows fetch" part. Can something be done without changing database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from 6.2 Hibernate team have started dropping support of unsupported DBs (please read [Hibernate ORM 6.2 - DB version support](https://in.relation.to/2023/02/15/hibernate-orm-62-db-version-support/), [Remove support for Oracle versions older than 19](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/HHH/issues/HHH-17090), [Remove support for Oracle versions older than 11.2](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/HHH/issues/HHH-15489)), however, some of those DBs are still (partially) supported via `hibernate-community-dialects` module. You need to add `hibernate-community-dialects` dependency to your project:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-community-dialects</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and, most probably, set `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect` to `Oracle10g` in `application.properties`

Comment: I tried your solution but get Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect :(

Comment: have you actually set `Oracle10g` or `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect`? The last one is not correct, correct values are: `Oracle10g` and `org.hibernate.community.dialect.Oracle10gDialect`